# Is there an easier way to remove glued-down hardwood than hammer & pry bar?

Tags: flooring, tools

In preparation for putting in a new hardwood floor, we've taken the existing laminate out and discovered what appears to be the original parquet hardwood floor underneath. The parquet squares are glued to the concrete subfloor, and I believe they must be taken out to accommodate the new floor (chevron hardwood, which requires a perfectly flat surface).

Is there an affordable, less labour-intensive way to remove these squares than chiseling them out with a hammer and pry bar?

Comment: A bear will make short work of parquet. Just put some grubs underneath it.

Comment: I think you're thinking of [Parkay](http://www.parkay.com/index.jsp). Bears can't get enough of that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It is a shame because it sounds as if your parquet is a good sound floor. If it is that hard to remove then you could lay straight onto it but I imagine there are height issues.

You can hire a small SDS masonry chisel which should get them up faster. Wear ear and eye protection.  I have a larger machine of this type on wheels that I use on commercial buildings. It saves hours of work.

Comment: A shame for sure.  If the parquet is at all salvageable they look amazing when refinished.

Comment: Fair point, but 'tis not to be in this case. :)